# PHP JavaScript MapBox trying figure out how to pass custom data for markers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, mapbox

Alright, trying to work with Mapbox http://www.mapbox.com, and I have finally came to a point where I think I got my maps working properly based on there examples with my setup. At this point I want to start passing custom data of my own for use with markers on the site. I know it has to be a particular format, an all else which is fine I'm sure I can figure out how to format it properly once I figure out how I invoke this custom like useage with data from my own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add markers with [the markers API, by making GeoJSON](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/single-marker/) - here's [the simple GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) spec, which you can make from PHP by creating the proper array structure and then using [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).